# Align text in navigation bar

Tags: css, text-alignment

Problem with aligning text in nav bar

Hi there

i have a problem with aligning my text in a navigation bar. I need the last text to move to the right of the bar so it stays with my search bar, and the other to stay on the left

But Im having issues getting this done, any help maybe?

Comment: `space-between` w/ 2 child elements

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for this and just apply  "margin-left: auto" to the last list item. Note that I got the basic layout (nav to the left and search to the right with flex (using flex-grow and flex-shrink repsectively).

The inside the nav - applying the flex styling to layout the list items and then on the :last-child using margin-left to force it to the right away from teh other list items.

UPDATE - following comments from OP - have amended it to have a second nav-list to the right of the search input. Much easier to split the list than trying to get the layout using float etc.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  flex-grow: 1
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-list li {
 padding: 4px 16px;
}


.search-wrapper {
  flex-shrink: 0;
   padding: 0 16px;
 )
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav-list">
     <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type ="search" placeholder="search" />
  </div>
     <ul class="nav-list nav-list-right">
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I can share the code I have as mine seems a but messed up, when using your code it does work but I need my last link to be on the right of the search bar

Comment: <div class="navbar">
          <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Shop Now</a>
          <a href="#">Sign up/Log in</a>
          <a href="#">Our Story</a>
          <a href="#">Contact us</a>
          <a href="#" >Shopping Cart</a>
          <div class="search">
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text"placeholder="Search..." name="search">
           </div>

Comment: .navbar { 
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #065A50;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  text-align: right;
  }

.navbar input[type=text] {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-right: 250px;
  font-size: 16px;
  
}
/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
    float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: @RichardHill - I didn't realise you needed the last link after the search. Two ways to achieve this easily - include the search in a list item (and therefore the li with the search inoput has the margni-left: auto)...  or alternatively - split the lst and put the desired content AFTER the search. Although this splits the nav - list - its much cleaner than trying to do the floating and other layout tricks.... Also - it may not need to be in a ul in the firstpl ace - you may be avble to just have a a element or other text etc.

Comment: Sorry yes, I should given a better explanation of what I needed......fantastic thanks! Ill give this a try and see how I go

Comment: @RichardHill You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**